# Replacing notebook SATA hard disk with SSD without reinstalling

Tags: laptop, hard-drive, ssd, migration, livecd

So there's a notebook (Lenovo Thinkpad Z61m) with a SATA hard disk, the SATA controller is configured for native AHCI operation & the OS is Windows XP. The hard disk is going to be replaced with an SSD which is larger.

I have an idea of how I'm going to do this, but I want to be sure there isn't something obvious I'm missing.

- Connect external USB drive
- Boot some flavour of Linux live CD
- Use `dd` to clone the SATA disk to the external drive
- Power off and replace the SATA disk with the SSD
- Boot the live CD
- Use `dd` to clone back from the external drive to the SSD

Does anyone have anything to add?

Comment: Looks great to me, just make sure that you use /dev/sdX and not /dev/sdXN to copy, as the latter will only grab the partition and not the boot sector.

Comment: @marcusw: you should add an answer rather than a comment, as comments can't gain you any rep.

Comment: Never use any OS less than Windows 7 on an ssd! Earlier version of windows do not support the ssd trim command and your drive may die in a year or so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dd probably won't work quite as you expect it to, as you really need something smarter than just a bit-for-bit copy of the raw drive/partition.

Check out [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/), [Acronis](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/), [DriveImageXML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm), [Ghost](http://www.symantec.com/themes/ghost/index.jsp) / [Ghost 4 Unix](http://www.feyrer.de/g4u/), and many others.

Comment: I've used Acronis without any problems.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why dd won't work? I expect it to copy the boot sector, partition table, data, etc. etc. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Graeme Unless the drive geometry is identical for both drives, you will have issues. dd will copy EVERY byte - which includes the partition table and other stuff that is really best created with the correct drive geometry.

Comment: Thanks. It didn't work and we ended up installing Windows 7 instead of trying to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to migrate my laptop's 500GB drive to a 128GB OCZ SSD in about an hour. The Windows partition was ~150GB (i.e. larger than my SSD) and the 2nd of 3 partitions.

1. Acquire SATA 2.5" -> USB adapter for about 20 USD/EUR.
2. Migrate data using (inexpensive) [Paragon's Migrate OS to SSD](http://www.paragon-software.com/technologies/components/migrate-OS-to-SSD/). 6 clicks and you're done.
3. Install SSD and watch your system boot up faster than you have ever *ever* seen.

Note: This tool ensures that your SSD partitions are aligned, which Windows 7 can and will take advantage of. I'm fairly certain that XP doesn't support this feature though.